# OpenGl box fullscreen

Tags: opengl, 3d, projection, perspective

I'd like to draw the inside of a box fullscreen (i.e. it should completely fill the viewport) using OpenGL. **The box should have perspective.**

I presume I'll have to change the dimensions of the box depending on the viewport size but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I'm trying to achieve something like the room in [this image](http://www.blitzcode.net/images/projects/project_127_big.png)

My question is: **how can I achieve this?**

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you encountered (and how accurate to you want it)? Just creating an open-sided box to fill the view is pretty simple. Producing the soft-edged shadows is quite a bit more work.

Comment: The problem is working out how to position the cube so it entirely fits the viewport. I haven't tried anything yet, I'm just figuring out how to do it.

Comment: That part is actually pretty trivial: just use the same coords for the fronts of the four "wall" quads as you passed to `glFrustum`. The usual viewport code will work just fine without modification (it's basically just telling OpenGL where to display its output, which you (nearly) always want as the full size of the window you're given). Just be aware that since you're told it to fill the view, you'll get linear distortion when/if the *shape* of the display area changes (i.e., square window->square box, oblong window->oblong box).

Comment: I was using gluPerspective to set up my projection matrix. I think I'll give glFrustrum a try, thanks.

Comment: If you'd like to change that comment to an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: @Jerry, you should probably turn that into an answer just so this q doesn't continue to be categorized as "unanswered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same coords for the fronts of the four "wall" quads as you passed to glFrustum. The usual viewport code will work just fine without modification (it's basically just telling OpenGL where to display its output, which you (nearly) always want as the full size of the window you're given). Just be aware that since you're told it to fill the view, you'll get linear distortion when/if the shape of the display area changes (i.e., square window->square box, oblong window->oblong box).

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit late after almost one year but seen that there is not a complete answear or at least i couldn't solve the problem with what is here i'll point you to this question wich can help for sure

[How to ensure that a plane perfectly fills the viewport in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792952/how-to-ensure-that-a-plane-perfectly-fills-the-viewport-in-opengl-es)