# How to ensure that a plane perfectly fills the viewport in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to create a flat plane such that it perfectly fills the viewport in an OpenGL ES application. I can achieve this effect by creating the plane and then experimentally moving it forwards and backwards until I get the right effect, but I'm certain that it must be possible to work out exactly how far away from the camera it should be. I would welcome any pointers!

I need to be accurate because the plane has a texture applied to it, which I want to fill the window and not be clipped at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want orthographic projection perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so - the reason being that I want to warp the plane (i.e. change it's height in certain places) and see the effect on the bitmap in perspective. I believe that that won't happen with an orthographic projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use glFrustum instead of gluPerspective to set the perspective projection. With glFrustum you define the projection in terms of a plane you want to display viewport-filling. Pseudocode:

```
aspect = win.width/win.height
bt = tan( fov/2 ) 
lr = bt * aspect

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
glFrustum( -lr * zclip.near,
            lr * zclip.near,
           -bt * zclip.near,
            bt * zclip.near,
            zclip.near, zclip.far)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()

vertices = [
    (-lr * planedist, -bt * planedist, -planedist),
    ( lr * planedist, -bt * planedist, -planedist),
    ( lr * planedist,  bt * planedist, -planedist),
    (-lr * planedist,  bt * planedist, -planedist)
]
draw_vertices(vertices)
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it sounds like exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, after your answer pointed me in the right direction, I worked out an alternative method with gluPerspective. Given a near clipping plane at 1.0, the clipping plane distance is then 1.0 / -tan(fov/2).

Comment: @PaulButcher: And if it isn't at 1.0? Could you make the formula more generic, please? So that I can feed fov, as well as nearp? I would be very grateful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Projecting rays through the screen/viewport corners onto your plane should give your the correct vertices for the corners.

Comment: So I understand you correctly - rather than move the plane forwards or backwards until it's right, you're suggesting that I have a "large" plane and then work out where to place the bitmap on it by projecting rays? Or can I use this technique to work out how far away to place the plane? Thanks!